# NSView setNeedDisplay:rect causes redrawing bigger area than needed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to redraw part of some NSView.

```
- (IBAction)onUpdateView:(id)sender
{
    NSRect updatedRect = ... // Redraw updated area only.
    [self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:updatedRect];
}
```

When I use this straightforward and obvious solution, Quartz Debug highlights redrawing of much bigger areas - up to the whole area of the view.

I noticed that if the call of [NSView setNeedsDisplayInRect] is deferred to the next run loop cycle, or I simply do [runloop runUntilDate:+0], the problem disappears:

```
- (IBAction)onUpdate:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:updatedRect];
    });
}
```

or

```
- (IBAction)onUpdateAndRunLoop:(id)sender
{
    [self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:updatedRect];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0]]; // EEW
}
```

but if setNeedsDisplayInRect is called in mouseDown handler, it works without all this hackery:

```
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent*)event
{
    NSPoint p = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

    int size = 100;
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:NSMakeRect(p.x-size/2, p.y-size/2, size, size)];
}
```

What's going on and what to do?

Isolated Xcode project for this problem is here: http://beta.kalinsky.ru/wtf/testRedraw.tar.gz

Comment: Does that view you want to redraw have a custom drawRect method? If so do you draw everything in there or do you respect the dirtyRect and only redraw stuff that's in that rect? Or maybe that view is clipped and also draws its offscreen content?

Comment: @HAS: sure, it was my first suspicion. drawRect method in attached project is literally "[NSBezierPath fillRect:dirtyRect];"

Comment: Have you found a better explanation than the one I provided below in answer and comments? Text and transparency add a major performance impact when drawing.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi, there's no explanation - all we have is undocumented weird behaviour and weird workarounds. I'm waiting for Apple DTS opinion. I sent it on Dec 3, but there's no response yet.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you so sure this is undesirable behavior? The behavior I'm seeing under Quartz Debugger shows that, when I hit the Update button, an intersection of the clicked button's rectangle and that of the passed dirtyRect is flashed. This is expected as the system coalesced all needed drawing within the same pass of the runloop (on mouse up) for efficiency.

Your other hacky methods bypass this behavior because the button's state is handled in one (actually two: mouse down and mouse up) passes and your view's update is handled in a subsequent pass. This is verified if you pay close attention to the update flashes in your deferred drawing clicks (button flashes on down, again on up, then your view's dirty area flashes). Clicks to the view itself involve nothing else (well, technically, its non-opaque ancestors), so the union of all views' dirty rects are confined to your requested rect.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It sounds reasonable, but I'm not sure that this behaviour is desirable and correct. I tried another experiment: I put a text label at one corner of main window and started to draw that funny squares at the opposite one. In this case QuartzDebug flashes the whole 2560x1600 area, and WindowServer uses up to ~50% CPU: http://beta.kalinsky.ru/wtf/deferred_vs_direct.png (the plot shows CPU usage of WindowServer process)

Comment: That does seem odd. What happens if you override your custom view's -isOpaque to return YES?

Comment: Wow, that completely fixed the problem in the attached xcodeproj :-) http://beta.kalinsky.ru/wtf/opaque_vs_transparent.png, source: http://beta.kalinsky.ru/wtf/testRedraw-opaque.tar.gz
But it's unclear for me why the system decides to repaint the whole area even if there're no views underneath.

Comment: If the view is opaque, the sysyem doesn't have to care what's behind it and doesn't have to blend a metric sh**-ton of layers with prettily antialiased text. If it isn't, there may be a lot of other graphical layers to composite. You may want to -setWantsLayer:YES on your view or one of its ancestors and possibly also consider using a CAText layer (in your custom view's layer hierarchy) instead of an NSTextField. YMMV but we'd need a lot more detail to offer more optimal details I think.

Comment: I also suspect there are NSVisualEffect precalculation shennanigans going on that are probably related to the Yosemite beta Finder-in-icon-view-mode scrolling performance problems. I think once you add text to the mix (on any layer) that system-provided knockout blending becomes a LOT more expensive. Especially when you consider the light/dark automatic label color behavior. Help it out by hinting opaqueness if possible and using layer backed views, etc.